# Firebase firestore indexing while in use

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

Could not find any posts on this so I thought I ask here. Is it ok to perform composite indexing based on the hint provided in the error:FAILED_PRECONDITION while the Firestore collection is still being written/read in production? This particular collection has a few hundreds of thousands of documents. And will probably take days to complete the indexing.

Also, how can I exempt the field thumb_url in the following structure from being auto-index?

```
{
    ...
    references: [
      0: {
            ...
            thumb_url: 'https://signed-url-to-the-image-resource'
         },
      1: {
            ...
            thumb_url: 'https://signed-url-to-the-image-resource'
         }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore can safely build an index while the data is being accessed. There is no need to stop accessing the database, while the index is being built.

Comment: Will doing so slow the access to the collection? I suppose I can switch off the computer once the index building starts?

Comment: There's no impact on performance guarantees while indexes are being updated.

Comment: Don't quite understand. So is there impact or not? Or there is no guarantees on performance during indexing?

Comment: @Shaun Performance wont be affected Don't worry.  No correlation between data accessing and index building

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the confirmation. By the way is there anyway to tell if indexing has completed?

Comment: Hey @Shaun. Anything else needed here?